# Re-nest nested data (using a reverse hoist)

Tags: r, tidyr

I am curious if a function exists for this specific type of task, which is analogous to `hoist()` but in reverse.

I have a nested data frame, which was created using `group_by() %>% nest()` syntax. I want to take that nested data frame, and then undo one of the columns by which it was grouped (such that this column would now be within the list-column).

So for the data here:

```
set.seed(22)
# Create Fake Data
flavor <- data.frame(
  temperature = sample(
    x = c('hot', 'cold'),
    size = 1500,
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  color = sample(c('red', 'blue', 'green'), 1500, TRUE),
  texture = sample(c('crumbly', 'crispy', 'wet', 'soft'), 1500, TRUE),
  flavor = sample.int(n = 100, size = 1500, replace = TRUE) / 100
)
```

I'd like to go from this data...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

flavor %>% 
  group_by(color, temperature) %>%
  nest()
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   color, temperature [6]
  temperature color data              
  <chr>       <chr> <list>            
1 cold        blue  <tibble [262 × 2]>
2 hot         red   <tibble [247 × 2]>
3 cold        green <tibble [250 × 2]>
4 cold        red   <tibble [252 × 2]>
5 hot         blue  <tibble [245 × 2]>
6 hot         green <tibble [244 × 2]>
```

To this data...

```
flavor %>% 
  group_by(color) %>%
  nest()
# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   color [3]
  color data              
  <chr> <list>            
1 blue  <tibble [507 × 3]>
2 red   <tibble [499 × 3]>
3 green <tibble [494 × 3]>
```

But without having to actually start with the original data frame and do the regrouping. Is this feasible? I could of course just `unnest()` the data and then regroup them and then nest them.

```
flavor %>% 
  group_by(color, temperature) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  unnest(cols = data) %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  nest()

# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   color [3]
  color data              
  <chr> <list>            
1 blue  <tibble [507 × 3]>
2 red   <tibble [499 × 3]>
3 green <tibble [494 × 3]>
```

I'm just curious if there is a way to accomplish this without having to actually unnest the data (or start from scratch). The behavior in mind is something analogous to [`hoist()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html) but in reverse (and applied to a nested data frame).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reframe` + `bind_rows`:

```r
flavor %>% 
  group_by(color, temperature) %>%
  nest() %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  reframe(data = list(bind_rows(data)))

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   color data              
#   <chr> <list>            
# 1 blue  <tibble [507 × 2]>
# 2 green <tibble [494 × 2]>
# 3 red   <tibble [499 × 2]>
```

Comment: Neat, just got new ideas where and how to use reframe :)  though I believe here the desired result also includes `temperature`.

Comment: Oh, right! I did not realize this

Answer (score 0):

using the Maël solution

```
lavor %>% 
  group_by(color, temperature) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, temperature, ~mutate(.x, temperature = .y))) %>% 
  group_by(color) %>%
  reframe(data = list(bind_rows(data)))
```